# PostgreSQL joining multiple table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have three tables `user`, `deposit` and `withdraw`.

`user`:

```
 | id | name    |
 | -: | :------ |
 |  1 | Lorem   |
 |  2 | Ipsum   |
 |  3 | Dolores |
```

`deposit`:

```
 user_id | amount
 ------: | -----:
       1 |   1000
       3 |   3000
```

`withdraw`:

```
 user_id | amount
 ------: | -----:
       1 |   2000
       2 |   3000
```

My question is how to join the table, expected result:

```
 id |  sum_deposit |  sum_withdraw
 -: | -----------: | ------------:
  1 |         1000 |          2000
  2 |         null |          3000
  3 |         3000 |          null
```

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Comment: Please correctly format your question and add what you've already tried and what result or error did you get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=0b5d4733c37ae3f1dc320d35d81836b5)

First `SUM()` the `deposits` and `withdraws` data and then do the `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM users u

LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT 
       user_id,
       SUM(amount)
   FROM deposit
   GROUP BY user_id
) d ON u.id = d.user_id

LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT 
       user_id,
       SUM(amount)
   FROM withdraw
   GROUP BY user_id
) w ON u.id = w.user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 WITH USERS AS 
  (
     SELECT 1 AS USER_ID,'LOREM' AS USER_NAME
         UNION ALL 
     SELECT 2 ,'IPSUM'
        UNION ALL
     SELECT 3,'DOLORES'
  ),
 DEPOSIT(ID,USER_ID,AMOUNT) AS  
  (
    SELECT 1,1,1000
       UNION ALL 
    SELECT 3,3,3000
  ),
WITHDRAW(ID,USER_ID,AMOUNT) AS  
 (
    SELECT 1,1,2000
      UNION ALL 
    SELECT 2,2,3000
 )
SELECT U.USER_ID,SUM(D.AMOUNT)AS DEPOSIT,
 SUM(W.AMOUNT)AS WITHDRAW
 FROM USERS AS U
 LEFT JOIN DEPOSIT AS D ON U.USER_ID=D.USER_ID
 LEFT JOIN WITHDRAW AS W ON U.USER_ID=W.USER_ID
 GROUP BY U.USER_ID;
```

Please try something like this

Comment: results of deposits and withdrawals do not match, if the deposit has 2 data and withdraws 1 data then it will get double data in withdraws